# How to use Django to get the name for the host server?

Tags: python, django, url, host

How to use Django to get the name for the host server?

I need the name of the hosting server instead of the client name?

Comment: I can't believe this process is so convoluted in Dj.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I generally put something like this in `settings.py`:

```
import socket

try:
    HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()
except:
    HOSTNAME = 'localhost'
```

Comment: Your solution does not work, if you use Docker. It will show the container ID instead of the URL.

Comment: His solution was written before docker existed. Sorry.

Comment: @antony.trupe came from memes?

Comment: Gotta link this here https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/jmnr07/that_is_a_good_excuse/

Comment: Someone deleted my comment from November, 22, 2016, which was worded as follows:
My solution was written before Docker existed. Sorry.

Comment: I was looking up the same topic right now and found this thread again xD

Answer (score 86):

If you have a request (e.g., this is inside a view), you can look at [`request.get_host()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) which gets you a complete locname (host and port), taking into account reverse proxy headers if any. If you don't have a request, you should configure the hostname somewhere in your settings. Just looking at the system hostname can be ambiguous in a lot of cases, virtual hosts being the most common.

Comment: In case i don't have a request, I need to hard-code domain name in settings variable?

Comment: for me `request.get_raw_uri()` did the job, as it also provided the protocol http(s). This is in Django 3 though, not sure when this was introduced.

Answer (score 11):

If you need to get `http(s)://hostname/` you can use the following:

`request.build_absolute_uri('/')`

All useful methods are listed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#methods)

Answer (score 8):

Just add to [@Tobu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8711377/1292238).
If you have a request object, and you would like to know the protocol (i.e. http / https), you can use [request.scheme](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.scheme) (as suggested by [@RyneEverett's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093999/how-to-use-django-to-get-the-name-for-the-host-server/27410255#comment51056498_27410255)).

Alternatively, you can do (original answer below):

```
if request.is_secure():
    protocol = 'https'
else:
    protocol = 'http'
```

Because [is_secure()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure) returns `True` if request was made with HTTPS.

Comment: Couldn't you just use [request.scheme](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.scheme)?

Comment: @RyneEverett thanks. didn't know about it (facepalm).

Answer (score 6):

Try `os.environ.get('HOSTNAME')`

Comment: When using this, be aware that some distro's only set HOST, while others only set HOSTNAME, and that many *export* neither by default.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, You can take with `request.get_host()` in your view/viewset. It returns `<ip:port>`

Answer (score 4):

If you have a request object, you can use this function:

```
def get_current_host(self, request: Request) -> str:
    scheme = request.is_secure() and "https" or "http"
    return f'{scheme}://{request.get_host()}/'
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to simplify this into `f"{request.scheme}://{request.get_host()}/"`?

Comment: From docs: A string representing the scheme of the request (http or https usually). So this might be even easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.get_raw_uri() # example https://192.168.32.181:10555/
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

To get my django server name I tried this

```py
host = f"{ request.scheme }://{ request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') }"
```

Comment: `REMOTE_ADDR` is usually the IP address of the client.   The only time that is going to be the host server is if the request is made from localhost.