# Python Socket script <-> HTML client

Tags: javascript, python, html, sockets, websocket

Using the following code I can create a Socket Server in my Raspberry Pi which works great if accessed via Socket clients like Android apps.

However, I would like to integrate websocket functionality to my website so I started trying to send a simple message via HTML textbox that the python script will receive and answer back.

The problem is **I cant get the HTML code to open, send and keep open the socket for communication**. I do acknowledge the html client connecting to python but cant get data as it seems the connection closes.

**Python code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#python3
# https://pythonprogramming.net/client-server-python-sockets/

import socket               # Websocket 
import sys                  # 
from _thread import *       # Used for multi-threading      The thread module has been renamed to _thread in Python 3.
import time                 # Used to create delays

# ******* WEBSOCKET VARIABLES *******
numberClients = 0
host = ''
PORT = 2223
# ******* WEBSOCKET VARIABLES *******

# ************************** FUNCTIONS **************************
def threaded_client(conn,address):      # receive as parameters, the connection object (conn), and the address object that contains the ip and port
    global numberClients
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))  # data should be bytes
    numberClients = numberClients + 1

    #           CHECK USER USING PASSWORD OR SOMETHING
    if ("192.168" in str(address[0])):
        print ("     VALID CLIENT!!")

        while True:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            if (data):
                reply = "" + 'Server output: '+ data.decode('utf-8').rstrip() + "\n"
                print(str(address[0]) + " - Clients(" + str(numberClients) + ") -> Data received: >" + data.decode('utf-8').rstrip() + "<")
            if not data:
                #print("no data")
                #break
                foo = 2
            try:
                conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))     # data should be bytes
            except Exception as e:
                foo = 1
        print("Thread connection closed by client: " + address[0])
        conn.close()
        numberClients = numberClients - 1

    else:
        print ("     INVALID CLIENT -> Thread connection closed by USER VALIDATION: " + address[0])
        conn.close()
        numberClients = numberClients - 1
# ************************** FUNCTIONS **************************




# ************************** SETUP **************************
print ("\n----------- Starting Websocket Python Program -----------\n")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   # "s" here is being returned a "socket descriptor" by socket.socket.
print(s)

# we are simply attempeting to bind a socket locally, on PORT 5555.
try:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)         # reuse the port number (in case we just got an error and port was not freed)
    s.bind((host, PORT))                # server side - take IN connections
    print ("Server started on port " + str(PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))
    print('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
    #sys.exit()
print('Socket bind complete')

s.listen(5)     # the "5" stands for how many incoming connections we're willing to queue before denying any more.

print('Waiting for a connection.')
# ************************** SETUP **************************



# ************************** MAIN LOOP **************************
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()         # code will stop here whilst waiting for a new connection. Old connections will be running in the threads
    print('Connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,addr))   
# ************************** MAIN LOOP **************************
```

One of the many **HTML** codes I have tried:

> ```
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>      function WebSocketTest()
>      {
>         if ("WebSocket" in window)
>         {
>            alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
>
>            // Let us open a web socket
>            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.20:5252/echo");
>            ws.onopen = function()
>            {
>               // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
>               ws.send("133:L1");
>               alert("Message is sent...");
>            };
>
>            ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
>            { 
>               var received_msg = evt.data;
>               alert("Message is received...");
>            };
>
>            ws.onclose = function()
>            { 
>               // websocket is closed.
>               alert("Connection is closed..."); 
>            };
>         }
>
>         else
>         {
>            // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
>            alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
>         }
>      }
>   </script>
>       </head>    <body>
>
>   <div id="sse">
>      <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
>   </div>
>       </body> </html>
> ```

As you can see things which are working:
- More than one client can connect
- Clients connecting from android app can send and receive messages and keep connection open
- html client is accepted but no message is send

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That's not a Websocket application you create with Python but a Socket application. Websocket is a protocol on top of HTTP which sits on top of TCP which are the actual sockets you've used in your Python application. To create a Websockets server with python you might try the [websockets](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets) library.

For more details about the difference see [Difference between socket and websocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973622/difference-between-socket-and-websocket) or [Differences between TCP sockets and web sockets, one more time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945345/differences-between-tcp-sockets-and-web-sockets-one-more-time) for the difference. For server code see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839054/websocket-server-in-python.

Comment: wow! Big mistake on my side. I would like to keep the python "socket" script as it is already working great. Is it possible to create a html socket client? My second objective will be to create an Android App to communicate with python socket.

Comment: @Serge: There is no standard interface for plain sockets in HTML. For Chrome have a look at [sockets_tcp](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp).

Comment: So given my objective: have a python script serving live fast information to an Android App and also to a HTML website. Should I modify my python script to use WebSocket instead of Sockets?

Comment: @Serge: if you want to support all (recent) browsers then you have to use WebSockets. For browser support see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets).

Comment: Will it be possible to communicate via an Android App also? Right now is very nice how I can use any android app client to connect to it. I would like to be able to continue doing this, but also html access.

Comment: seems like this is a good starting point: https://gist.github.com/jkp/3136208 I have managed to make the above html code work, and downloaded an Android app which works. Now time to find out how to allow multiple clients