# Electron TCP socket

Tags: sockets, electron

I'm using Electron and I need to be able to send/receive from a server using tcp sockets. I have the client set up and I'm able to send to the server (I can confirm the server is receiving this lines).

However, I can't seem to figure out how to "listen/read" from the server when it replies back to me. This is the function I'm using to handle communication between my client and the socket server

```
var net = require('net');

function mySocket(message){
    socketClient = net.connect({host: MY_IP, port: MY_PORT},  () => {
        socketClient.setEncoding('utf8');
        socketClient.write(message);
    });

    socketClient.on('data', (data) => {
        alert(data);
    });

    socketClient.on('end', () => {
        alert('Disconnected');
    });
}
```

Running this function succesfully sends a message to the server:

```
"mySocket('Hello, its me)"
```

However the "reading" is not working. The server is sending the reply but my client is not able to read it in order to show it back to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Side note, the server is not a Node.JS server. It's a simple socket server done in, I belief, Pascal. I'm able to send/get replies from this same server using TCP sockets in Android, Java, Ruby, and many others so it should be able to work with Electron.

Comment: The little code you posted is not the reason for your problem. We need a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You'll likely find the problem while you make a MCVE.

Comment: @snwflk , I've added a MCVE (I think). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because you're running on a browser, are you using websockets electron app? [websocket vs socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973622/difference-between-socket-and-websocket#4973689)

Comment: This is suppose to be a comment not an answer

Comment: Users need 50 rep to comment. This always trips me up.

Comment: Sorry ladies, just tryin to help someone here heheh :)

Comment: Hey @leandrojesus-programmer, welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm not using websockets.

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea thanks :D you should try using websockets on your electron app, instead of normal sockets

Comment: I can't use websockets because the I need to connect o an existing service and it runs under a tcp/ip socket. I figured websockets could be a better alternative, but unfortuntely it's not something I can work with for this particular case. I appreciate your suggestion though.