# Is there a way to send data from javascript to an exe file

Tags: javascript, c++

I was making a simple website where when you put in an username and password, It would send it to a c++ executable that would save the data in a txt document.

the executable works fine, but I can't find a way to send the data to the executable.

I tried window.open(), but then, It started to download the exe file.

this is the code of the c++ executable

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char main () {
   char name[100];
   char password[100];
   cin >> name;
   cin >> password;

   ofstream outfile;
   outfile.open ("data.txt", ios_base::app);
   outfile << name <<"; " << password << endl;
   outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: You should start reading sockets in c++

Comment: This depends entirely on the operating system and web server being used.  Since the question does not appear to specify either, no authoritative answer is possible.

Comment: Where is your exe file located? On the server or on a client? For the server you can try to setup web server and call your exe from there, Then you pass data from javascript to web server and back with ajax

Comment: it is on the computer.

Comment: I dont use the web server because I don't know how

Comment: I use windows os

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called *interproccess comunication*. It's quite common, however, in the traditional sense, it can't be done between a web page javascript and a standard desktop app. **Still, you can emulate it**, one possible way is using sockets/WebSockets in your desktop app and WebSockets in your web page's javascript. The other way could be implementing a simple REST API with two endpoints, one on the app and one on the web page server.

The socket approach is easier, for more info on it, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973622/12188799). Also check this [WebSocket tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) and this [C++ WebSocket library](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp).

Following up on your comment, all of this can be done in a single computer, in fact, that's what I had in mind when answering.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to post the Internet. so I don't have a server.

Comment: The solution he proposed does not require the internet. Sockets are able to work within a computers internal processes to communicate. This discussion is great for the matter: https://superuser.com/questions/1137897/does-a-localhost-request-connect-to-the-network