# Using socket in Vxml and Voice browsers

Tags: sockets, websocket, browser, voice, vxml

I'm trying to link my backend with my vxml code and and frontend application (web-browser based). I want the backend to send out data to both my vxml application and web based one in sync.

So i came across sockets in network programming. Being new to voice browser not sure how I'm gonna link sockets there. Any help, source or guidelines regarding the same are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VoiceXML standard doesn't include support for websockets. Your platform might, though I've never seen it supported. I have seen linking of a VoiceXML and web application, but that was done through SCXML or doing some messy polling from the voicexml layer between prompt/input timeouts.  SCXML has the advantage of interrupting a voicexml call flow at the trigger of an event.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973622/difference-between-socket-and-websocket i refered this posts comment and it pointed out WebSockets typically run from browsers connecting to Application Server over a protocol similar to HTTP that runs over TCP/IP. So they are primarily for Web Applications that require a permanent connection to its server. On the other hand, plain sockets are more powerful and generic. They run over TCP/IP but they are not restricted to browsers or HTTP protocol. They could be used to implement any kind of communication.

Comment: For two web browsers, web sockets are a very good solution. This issue is that VoiceXML platforms don't support websockets. If you are building your own VoiceXML platform, this would be a nice enhancement. Most users, however, are running their applications on other people's/company's implementation.