# Accessing Heroku's url root in Django settings.py

Tags: python, django, heroku

I need to access the root url of my Heroku app. I have several apps for this project (e.g., staging, production) and I'd like to programmatically set this value in my settings file. What I want is:

```
URL_ROOT = 'http://silly-name-1234.herokuapp.com'
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093999/how-to-use-django-to-get-the-name-for-the-host-server), I have tried the following:

```
import socket
HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()
URL_ROOT = HOSTNAME
```

But, this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

`heroku config:add BASE_IRI=http://silly-name-1234.herokuapp.com` at the heroku cli

after that do a `os.environ.get('BASE_IRI', 'localhost')` in your `settings.py`

Comment: Thanks! This worked well. I also found this Heroku documentation to be useful: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: What does the IRI stand for? BASE_IRI seems an unusual choice.

Comment: Yeah I found it in some places. It comes from the non-English part of the world. It is URI (Uniform resource identifier) internationalized beyond ascii to unicode standards for URIs in Arabic, Chinese et al. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier

Answer (score -1):

Try `os.environ.get('HOSTNAME')`

Comment: This returns 'None', both on my local machine and when deployed on Heroku.